# Java CertificateException in Domino 9 when trying to access HTTPS URL

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, https, ibm-domino

When we upgraded our Domino development server from 8.5.3 to 9 the HTTPS connections from Java code to sites having *GoDaddy* certificate stopped working. Connections to servers having *DigiCert* certificate work fine. This happens in both agents and XPages.

Here is an XPage sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad>
             <![CDATA[#{javascript:new java.net.URL("https://www.sslshopper.com/").openStream();]]>
    </xp:this.beforePageLoad>
</xp:view>
```

I've also tried with `UrlConnection`. Here is the exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: 3659
    com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:15)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:460)
    com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:294)
    com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:533)
    com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:55)
    com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:581)
    com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:11)
    com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:394)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:44)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:496)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:528)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:505)
    com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:83)
    com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:31)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1184)
    com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:40)
    java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1022)
```

...

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: 3659
com.ibm.domino.napi.ssl.DominoX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(DominoX509TrustManager.java:98)
    com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:468)
    com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:581)
    com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:11)
    com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:394)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:44)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:496)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:528)
    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:505)
    com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:83)
    com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:31)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1184)
    com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:40)
    java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1022)
```

I imported the GoDaddy certificates to domino_path\jvm\lib\security\cacerts keystore according to these instructions:

http://drcs.ca/blog/adding-godaddy-intermediate-certificates-to-java-jdk/

But that did not help and I also imported *gd-class2-root.crt* with no results. I also tried renaming the *cacerts* file and copying the one from 8.5.3 server but it did not help either. I've been booting HTTP and Domino server after these changes.

Of course I could use Java code that does not care about certificates but I believe that's not a great solution for production. Also we have code in a lot of different places (including JARs) which make HTTPS connection to this URL.

**Update 1**

This is in *error-log-0.xml*:

> Certificate with subject CN=www.sslshopper.com, OU=Domain Control
>   Validated, O=www.sslshopper.com, issued by SERIALNUMBER=07969287,
>   CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority,
>   OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.",
>   L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US, **is not trusted**. Validation failed with
>   error 3659.

I think this message is quite clear. I also noticed that `System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")` returns null but that happens also in 8.5.3 server where this works. I tried setting the trustStore with `setProperty` but the error is still the same.

**Update 2**

It works with [Simon's code](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Connecting_to_a_Domino_server_over_SSL_in_Java_using_a_self_signed_certificate._#+Creating+a+sample+Java+application+to+connect+to+the+server+) that uses `createSocket`. But all our code use `java.net.URL`, `UrlConnection`, `HttpsUrlConnection` or Apache HTTP Client. Some of these are provided by 3rd party as a JAR. We cannot change all those to use `createSocket`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug mode to get more details as to the nature of the failure? eg. System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I added that but don't see any additional logging (maybe I don't know where to look). However I found a bit more info when looking at the logs, will update the question. It would be interesting to know if this happens to you also with the above sample code.

Comment: You need to set your trust store. Here is some sample code: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Connecting_to_a_Domino_server_over_SSL_in_Java_using_a_self_signed_certificate._#+Creating+a+sample+Java+application+to+connect+to+the+server+

Comment: It's quite a big change if Domino 9 does not use the *cacerts* keystore by default any more! I've already tried `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:/blahblah); System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pw");` but that did not help. I guess I need to copy paste the whole code from the URL you provided and try with that.

Comment: yea, I'd say try that sample code. If that works you can rule out an issue with your certificates.

Comment: Yes it works. But I don't know what to try next. I think there will be a ticket coming to you :-)

Comment: That would be my next suggestion if no joy here. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So for Domino 9, as the new feature OpenSocial was added, a lot of functionality was changed around certificates to make it easier to maintain.

As such there is a new API "com.ibm.domino.napi.ssl.DominoX509TrustManager". What this API does is now check the Domino certificates for the related trusted certificate which is also cross certified against the server certificate.

It checks first in the CACERTS. If it can't find this, then it will check the Domino certificates.

So in order to get the code above to work you need to do the following.

1. Open the Domino Administrator client and select the ""People and Groups -> Certificates".

   [image: people and groups tab, certificates view]
2. In the actions menu select "Import Internet Certificates".

   [image: menu setting]
3. Select the related certificate file to import using the file dialog. It may ask you for the file structure when importing, so select the correct structure if needed. It should appear in the view once completed.

   [image: View showing certificate imported.]
4. Open the document and from the actions menu select "Create Cross Certificate".

   [image: menu option of create cross certificate]
5. A dialog pops up. You select the certificate and click OK.

   [image: cross certificate dialog]
6. Next dialog make sure you have it set correctly for your server.  ie. The right server and certifier. Click Cross Certify when done.

   [image: Issue cross certificate dialog]

This should create a cross certificate in the view:

[image: view showing cross certificate]

At this point you need to restart the HTTP process with the following commands.

```
tell http quit 
load http
```

Comment: Thanks Simon! Btw. I could not get it to work with CACERTS so for me it looks like it does not check the CACERTS file.

Comment: It appears it needs a cross certificate created by the Server certificate. So that would need to be in the CACERTS as well. Steps above save you having to import that as well. The earlier steps we were just putting in the GoDaddy certificates alone. If it is still failing in CACERTS with the cross certificate let me know and I'll create an SPR. Cheers! :)

Comment: OK thanks! I'm happy with the Domino Directory solution and no need to go back to CACERTS.